# SQL:Show column only if has data in it

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle11g

Suppose I have a table like this:

```
name | age | experience
abc  |  18 | 0
def  |  19 | 0
efg  |  20 | 0
```

I want to select the experience column only if any one value is greater than zero.
In this case, my `SQL` query should return only name and age and not experience.

If experience of lets say "efg" is greater than 0, then query should return name, age and experience.
I have tried following query

```
SELECT  EXISTS (SELECT name,age,experience FROM emp_info )
   AND NOT
   EXISTS (SELECT experience FROM emp_info WHERE experience=0 );
```

But it is not working.

Comment: Provide better examples.

Comment: How is it not working? Also, a little confused... If experience > 0, then only select experience column? Or do you mean if experience <= 0, then select the other 2 columns, so experience is only shown where it's > 0?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: Try: `SELECT name,age,experience FROM emp_info WHERE experience > 0`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:-

```
IF ((select max(experience)FROM emp_info) > 0)
    SELECT name,age,experience FROM emp_info
ELSE
    SELECT name,age FROM emp_info
```

Answer (score 1):

In almost all relational databases, your queries have to return fixed numbers of columns, i.e the same number of columns for all rows.  So what you are asking for isn't reasonable.  You could probably get something like this to work on `Informix` due to jagged tables support, but that's the only one I can think of.

Other options you have include serializing to `JSON` in your query, or generating `XML` but that's a bit advanced for this and it is not clear this is what you want.

Normally we handle this on the front end, not in the database query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT name, age, NULLIF(experience, 0) from emp_info
```

Your question is kind of tricky because returning different set of column depending on the result is maybe not what you want to do, you could do it directly from your code, not from your SQL projection.

Answer (score 0):

This may work :

```
if(experience > 0)
  begin
    SELECT name,age,experience FROM emp_info
  end
else
  begin
    SELECT name,age FROM emp_info
  end
```