# Query that shows all rows but not all data in all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Imagine this database:

| CustomerID | ItemID | EventType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 123 | In Stock |
| ABC | 456 | On Order |
| DEF | 134 | Disc |
| DEF | 789 | On Order |

I want to run a report that will show me all of these records, but will only show me the status if the item is On Order.

So the output looks like this:

| CustomerID | ItemID | EventType |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC | 123 |  |
| ABC | 456 | On Order |
| DEF | 134 |  |
| DEF | 789 | On Order |

Is there a way to do this?

I found this answer: [SQL:Show column only if has data in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42340811/sqlshow-column-only-if-has-data-in-it) and tried this:

```
if ((select EventType from InventoryEvents) = 'On Order')
    select ItemID, CustomerID, EventType from InventoryEvents
else
    select ItemID, CustomerID from InventoryEvents
```

And got this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I'm very close to putting a conditional format on the output in Excel that writes the data I don't want in white.  But of course, I'm designing a report for my boss and want it work-proof on their end.

Answer (score 3):

You want a [`case expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to conditionally show the EventType.

```
select ItemID, CustomerID
  , case when EventType = 'On Order' then EventType else '' end EventType
from InventoryEvents;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want a [`CASE` expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
SELECT  CustomerID, 
        ItemID, 
        CASE WHEN EventType <> 'On Order' THEN '' ELSE EventType END AS EventType 
FROM    InventoryEvents;
```